# Windows Terminal SSH Key Mapping

Tags: windows-10, ssh, keymap, windows-terminal

When ssh-ing from the new Windows Terminal to a Linux machine (I am not using WSL), the home/end/page up/down keys do not map correctly when typing in the Linux terminal (bash shell); they give tildes (~) instead. Note, however, that when I open a text file with vim in the terminal, they do act as expected.

Is there a way to change/set the mappings that the Windows Terminal uses? I have a profile set to automatically ssh into the Linux machine, so maybe something can be added to the profile in the settings.json file?

Comment: What does `echo $TERM` show?  Also, what `ssh` client are you using?  You mention that it is *not* from WSL, but you don't say what it *is* - Windows OpenSSH client?  Git bash?  Putty?  Something else?

Comment: The ssh client is Windows 10 OpenSSH (accessed through PowerShell) and `echo $TERM` gives `xterm-256color`.

Comment: Can you try installing a [more recent](https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH) OpenSSH build? (Just unpack it to C:\ and add to $PATH, don't overwrite the Windows files.)

Comment: I'm on a work-managed computer, so may not be able to install a newer version (will look into it). Is there a specific change or update addressing this issue with the later versions?